# Short range stereo vision

Tags: computer-vision, cameras, stereo-vision

I am designing a stereo vision system for short depth range (15 cm to 35 cm) and I have some problems about baseline, focal length and depth range.

1. My application is to scan an animal tissue (meat, chicken breast)
   with the stereo vision system with a depth range between 15 cm and
   35 cm, which is attached to a robotic arm. In this case, I need to
   choose a short baseline for short depth range and a short focal
   length. However, I have no idea how to pick these values (baseline
   and focal length) and choose the specific camera.
2. Most of the commercial stereo camera are good for depth range 50 cm to 300 cm and they have a relative large baseline (6 cm to 10 cm). I am wondering if there any recommendations for the built-in stereo camera system that can target at short range (15 cm to 35 cm).
3. If I need to build the stereo system from two digital cameras for short depth range? What kind of parameters I need to consider? (except for focal length, baseline).

Answer (score 1):

Check-out this paper ["Theory of Stereo vision system"](http://prod.optoiq.com/content/dam/VSD/NextGen/5-3D-2.pdf) from e-con Systems. They go an equation for figuring out depth range based on focal length, baseline, and other characteristics. Should be able to manipulate their equation to figure out what baseline, and focal length would be good for your system. As well as help figure out what hardware you might need or be able to get away with.